# Room database - Data doesn't show in the first time

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-room

When I populate my data inside my Database class, I called my getAllStudents method from StudentDao in MainActivity, but when I run the app ,in the first time my textview doesn't show the data. When I run the app second time ,only this time my textview shows the data. What is the problem ?
Here is mycode:

Student class

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
public class Student {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int ID;
private String name;
private String email;
private String phoneNumber;

public Student(String name, String email, String phoneNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

StudentDao

```
@Dao
public interface StudentDAO {
@Insert
void InsertSingleStudent(Student student);
@Insert
void InsertAllStudents(List<Student> students);
@Delete
void DeleteSingleStudent(Student student);
@Update
void UpdateSingleStudent(Student student);
```

Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {Student.class},version =1 ,exportSchema = false)
public abstract  class UniDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public abstract StudentDAO studentDAO();
private static UniDatabase instance;
public static synchronized  UniDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (null==instance){
        instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,UniDatabase.class,"uni_db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addCallback(initialCallback)
                .build();
    }

    new PopulateInitialData(instance).execute();
    return instance;
}
private static RoomDatabase.Callback initialCallback=new RoomDatabase.Callback() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);

    }
};
private static class PopulateInitialData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;
    public PopulateInitialData(UniDatabase db) {
        this.studentDAO=db.studentDAO();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<>();
        studentList.add(new Student("Cemal","cemal@gmail","555"));
        studentList.add(new Student("Rıza","riza@gmail","123"));
        studentDAO.InsertAllStudents(studentList);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Main Activity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private TextView textView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    UniDatabase db = UniDatabase.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    ArrayList<Student> students = (ArrayList<Student>) 
 db.studentDAO().getAllStudents();


    String text = "";
    for (Student s : students) {
        text += "Id: " + s.getID() + "\nName: " + s.getName() + "\nEmail: " + 
 s.getEmail();

    }
    textView.setText(text);

 }
 }
```

Comment: "the first time my textview doesn't show the data" is the data there the first time? if not, that's one problem. If it is, you can cut all DAO stuff out from your post, since it isn't relevant.

Comment: I mean that when I run the app first time in my device, textview doesn't show anything. But when I close the app, and restart it in my Android device, the textview shows the data this time.

Answer (score 0):

See, If you can recreate that problem by first deleting the database from the device or emulator, then running the code. If it happens again there is something wrong with your database creation.

I think that because your database is running in an AsyncTask it never coordinates with your Main thread to let it know that the data is ready. When you run the app a second time the data is already there, because the AsyncTask completed on your first run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my Android device I cleared the database inside the app, after I run the app from Android studio , but the problem is same.
Is it also possible that I am using Async Task,just because it is deprecated?